# What exactly is data.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

What exactly is data.stackexchange.com? I cannot understand, regardless of how much I read about it. It would be helpful if someone explained.

Comment: Please add a brief description of you search/research efforts. Ref. [ask]. By the way, have you already read the tag wiki of [tag:data-explorer]?

Comment: You can find the tag wiki of [tag:data-explorer] on https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info

Comment: Well... I saw it anyways. Your previous one worked just about fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, also known as SEDE.  If you click the [help link at the top](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) you'll learn more about how to use it.

SEDE is not part of Stack Exchange, though SE assists with database updates and provides access to it through their domain. SEDE is an open-source project maintained by members of the SE community.